# Piecewise with differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, piecewise

I have the following differential system. The calibration I use is as follows

```
paramFinal = {rho -> 0.025, R -> 0.25, alpha -> 0, k -> -0.55, g -> 1.2, C0 -> 3, C1 -> 0.1, sbar -> 10, \[Eta] -> 8.5, hbar -> 0.5, Hbar -> 23.5};
```

The differential system is

```
dec = W'[t] == -( rho + k*rho*C1 *H[t]/W[t] - k C1 R/W[t] - rho (g + k C0)/W[t]);

des = H'[t] ==  -(R - (1 - alpha) W[t]);
```

With NDSolve, I can solve the problem without any problem but I would like to restrict the variable $H[t]$ such that it does not go below $Hbar$ and once it hits $Hbar$, it stays there. I try to use Piecewise function as follows

```
pdec = Piecewise[{W'[t] == -(rho + k*rho*C1 *H[t]/W[t] - k C1 R/W[t] - rho (g + k C0)/W[t]), Hbar < H[t], {Hbar, Hbar > H[t]}}];

pdes = Piecewise[{H'[t] ==  -(R - (1 - alpha) W[t]), Hbar < H[t], {Hbar, Hbar > H[t]}}];

nsba3aa = NDSolve[{pdec /. paramFinal, pdes /. paramFinal, W[0] == 0.275, H[0] == 25, {W[t], H[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

I have the following error message and I cannot figure out where is the problem

> Piecewise::pairs: The first argument {(W^[Prime])[t]==-rho+(C1 k
>   R)/W[t]+((g+C0 k) rho)/W[t]-(C1 k rho
>   H[t])/W[t],HbarH[t]}} of Piecewise is not a list of
>   pairs. >>

Comment: `H[t]` appears to be an increasing function, and `H[0]>Hbar`, so you don't need to force `H[t]>Hbar`: this is implemented automatically.

Comment: You're using `Piecewise` blindly. Please start from checking document of `WhenEvent`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of little errors in your code:

1. As the error message suggests, `Piecewise` takes a list of pairs as an argument.  The structure in your code is `Piecewise[{eqn1, cond1, {eqn2, cond2}}]`; it needs to be `Piecewise[{{eqn1, cond1}, {eqn2, cond2}}]` instead.
2. The `Piecewise` should be on the right hand side, since the `eqn2` isn't a differential equation by itself.  Use `W'[t] == Piecewise[...]` instead.
3. I think you want eqn2 to be `0` not `Hbar` to keep `H[t]>=Hbar`.
4. You need to define `tmax`.
5. The initial conditions need to be in the same list as the differential equations in `NDSolve.`
6. I prefer to solve for `{W, H}` not `{W[t], H[t]}`.

Together:

```
tmax = 100;
pdec = W'[t] == Piecewise[{
  {-(rho + k*rho*C1*H[t]/W[t] - k C1 R/W[t] - rho (g + k C0)/W[t]), Hbar < H[t]},
  {0, Hbar > H[t]}}];

pdes = H'[t] == Piecewise[{
  {-(R - (1 - alpha) W[t]), Hbar < H[t]}, {0, Hbar > H[t]}}];

nsba3aa = NDSolve[{pdec /. paramFinal, pdes /. paramFinal, 
  W[0] == 0.275, H[0] == 25}, {W, H}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
```

We can't see that it works, since `H[t]>Hbar` in this example:

```
Plot[Evaluate[H[t] /. nsba3aa], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but if you flip the sign of `H'[t]` you will find that it does what you ask:
[image: Mathematica graphics]